# How to fix GPS location call currentloaction null error in an API call?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am calling an Openweather API using current GPS location. But I get an exception showing that currentlocation is called on null.

I can show it on the screen using text widget. But I get null exception when I am calling for the API.

`Text('${currentPosition.latitude.toStringAsFixed(2)} ${currentPosition.longitude}'),`

```
  void initState() {
    getCurrentLocation().then((position) {
      currentPosition = position;
    });

    super.initState();

    loadWeather();
  }
```

This the API call function:

```
Future loadWeather() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    final lat = currentPosition.latitude.toStringAsFixed(2);
    final lon = currentPosition.longitude.toStringAsFixed(2);
    // This part is showing null

    final openUviToken = 'API';
    final openWeatherToken = 'API';

    final weatherResponse = await http.get(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=${openWeatherToken}&lat=${lat.toString()}&lon=${lon.toString()}');


    if (weatherResponse.statusCode == 200) {
      return setState(() {
        weatherData = new WeatherData.fromJson(
          jsonDecode(weatherResponse.body),
        );
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

I tried Hemanth Raj's code already. The app get stuck in a loading state but when I click the button for the loadWeather function, it works. So problem persist only when the app is launched.

This is the load weather button. I just call this function in a column.

```
IconButton refreshButton() {
    return IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  tooltip: 'Refresh',
                  onPressed: loadWeather,
                  color: Colors.white,
                );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your are calling `loadWeather` before the future of `getCurrentLocation` is complete.

Change your `initState` like:

```
  void initState() {
    getCurrentLocation().then((position) {
      currentPosition = position;
      loadWeather();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried this code already. The app get stuck in a loading state. but when I click the button for the loadWeather function, it works.  So problem persist only when the app is launched.

Comment: Can you post more code. Where is the button for load weather?